# Show all installed packages which are not dependencies

Tags: package-management, debian, administration

I would like to clean my fresh Xubuntu installation a bit. To do this I would like to print all installed packages that are not installed as dependencies. In other worlds I would like to list all packages on which no installed package depends.

Answer (score 5):

A really great way to list "orphans" (packages that nothing depends on, and you have not explicitly installed) is `deborphans`.

You can list the installed packages for which no installed package depends on with:

```
aptitude search '~i ! ~R ~i'
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/can-aptitude-group-or-search-for-packages-which-nothing-depends-on)